# Distance format in haystack 'distance' lookup

Tags: django, spatial, django-haystack

While making [spatial search](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/spatial.html) in haystack, you can get the [distance](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/spatial.html#ref-spatial) to the objects found. As a result you get something like `0.393195738686 km`, so I wonder if I can specify float format and unit name (maybe localized) for the result.
PS I'm using elasticsearch as a backend, if it matters

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed, that `distance` lookup returns `Distance` objects, so I could format it in the templatetag in django:

```
@register.filter(name='distanceformat')
    def distanceformat(value, places=1):
    format_string = "%%.%df km" % places
    return format_string % value.km
```